# ¿Cómo disminuir y actualizar stock de la tabla artículo de una base de datos mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Tengo la siguiente duda de ¿cómo restar y actualizar el stock? de la tabla articulo, estoy desarrollando una aplicación web, utilizo PHP y MySQL.
Ahora bien, la estructura de mi tabla es el siguiente:

```
Código SQL
-- -----------------------------------
TABLE cliente (
idCliente varchar(20) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
claveCliente varchar(20) NOT NULL,
denominacion varchar(30) NOT NULL,
nombre varchar(25) NOT NULL,
apellidoPaterno varchar(30) NOT NULL,
apellidoMaterno varchar(30) NOT NULL,
fechaRegistro datetime NOT NULL,
rfc varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
aux int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

TABLE articulo (
idArticulo varchar(20) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
codigoArticulo varchar(20) NOT NULL,
codigoAlterno varchar(20) NOT NULL,
marca varchar(60) NOT NULL,
modelo varchar(60) NOT NULL,
descripcionArticulo varchar(300) NOT NULL,
unidadDeCompra int(11) NOT NULL,
unidadDeVenta int(11) NOT NULL,
factor int(11) NOT NULL,
inventarioMinimo int(11) NOT NULL,
inventarioMaximo int(11) NOT NULL,
unidadesExistentes int(11) NOT NULL, --aquí es el stock
unidadesVendidas int(11) NOT NULL,
localizacion varchar(20) NOT NULL,
idCategoria varchar(20) NOT NULL,
idDepartamento varchar(20) NOT NULL,
idProveedor varchar(20) NOT NULL,
fechaDeRegistro datetime NOT NULL,
aux int(11) NOT NULL
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
-- -----------------------------------
```

Mi código para hacer la inserción de los registros funciona correctamente, el problema es que tengo dudas de cómo desarrollar esa parte de restar y actualizar stock de la tabla articulo.
Las tablas que se insertan de registros al hacer la compra son las siguientes:

```
Código SQL
--------------------------
TABLE carrito (
idCarrito varchar(20) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
idCliente varchar(20) NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY,
idSesion varchar(64) NOT NULL,
fechaHora datetime NOT NULL,
aux int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
-- ---------------------
TABLE venta (
idVenta varchar(20) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
idCliente varchar(20) NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY,
idSesion varchar(64) NOT NULL,
totalArticulos int(11) NOT NULL,
totalVenta decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
observaciones varchar(100) NOT NULL,
fechaDeRegistro datetime NOT NULL,
codigoVenta varchar(25) NOT NULL,
aux int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
------------------------
TABLE contenido_carrito (
idContenidoCarrito int(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
idCarrito varchar(20) NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY,
idCliente varchar(20) NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY,
idSesion varchar(64) NOT NULL,
idArticulo varchar(20) NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY,
codigoArticulo varchar(20) NOT NULL,
codigoAlterno varchar(20) NOT NULL,
costo decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
unidades int(11) NOT NULL,
subTotal decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
fechaDeRegistro datetime NOT NULL,
aux int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
---------------------------------------
TABLE detalle_venta (
idDetalleVenta int(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
idVenta varchar(20) NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY,
idArticulo varchar(20) NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY,
codigoArticulo varchar(20) NOT NULL,
codigoAlterno varchar(20) NOT NULL,
unidades int(11) NOT NULL,
precioDeVenta decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
subTotal decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
fechaDeRegistro datetime NOT NULL,
codigoVenta varchar(25) NOT NULL,
aux int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
----------------------------------------
```

Ahora bien, el código PHP es el siguiente, obtengo los datos del formulario:

```
<?php
  if (isset($_POST['place_order'])) {
      require 'php/lib-generadorID.php';


      $idCarrito    = mysqli_real_escape_string($ConexionBD, 
      generarIDCARRITO());
      $idSesion     = mysqli_real_escape_string($ConexionBD,  
      generarIDSESSION());
      $idVenta      = mysqli_real_escape_string($ConexionBD,  
      generarIDVENTA());
      $codigoVenta= mysqli_real_escape_string($ConexionBD,  codigoVenta());
      $numCuenta  = mysqli_real_escape_string($ConexionBD,  
      generaNumeroCuenta());
      $cantidadArticulos = count($_SESSION["shopping_cartMT"]);

      $order_details = "";

      foreach ($_SESSION["shopping_cartMT"] as $keys => $values) {
         $sql_cart = "
          INSERT INTO carrito (idCarrito,idCliente,idSesion,fechaHora,aux) 
          VALUES ('$idCarrito','$idCliente','$idSesion',NOW(),'1')";

         $sql_venta = "
         INSERT INTO venta (idVenta, idCliente, idSesion, totalArticulos, 
         totalVenta, observaciones, fechaDeRegistro, codigoVenta, aux)
         VALUES('$idVenta', '$idCliente', '$idSesion', '$cantidadArticulos', 
         '$totalFin','PENDIENTE', NOW(), '$codigoVenta', '1')";

         $order_details .= "
         INSERT INTO contenido_carrito (idCarrito,idCliente, 
         idSesion,idArticulo,codigoArticulo,codigoAlterno, 
         costo,unidades,subTotal,fechaDeRegistro,aux)
         VALUES('$idCarrito','$idCliente','$idSesion',
         '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($ConexionBD,
         $values["product_id"]). "',
         '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($ConexionBD, 
         $values["product_codArticulo"]). "', '" . 
          mysqli_real_escape_string($ConexionBD, 
          $values["product_codAlterno"]). "',
          '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($ConexionBD, 
          $values["product_price"])    . "',
          '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($ConexionBD, 
          $values["product_quantity"]) . "',
          '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($ConexionBD, 
          $values["product_quantity"]*$values["product_price"]) . "',
          NOW(),
          '1'
          );

          INSERT INTO detalle_venta (idVenta, idArticulo, codigoArticulo, 
          codigoAlterno, unidades, precioDeVenta, subTotal, fechaDeRegistro, 
          codigoVenta, aux)
          VALUES('$idVenta',
          '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($ConexionBD, 
          $values["product_id"]) 
          . "', '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($ConexionBD, 
          $values["product_codArticulo"]) . "',
          '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($ConexionBD, 
          $values["product_codAlterno"])  . "',
          '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($ConexionBD, 
          $values["product_quantity"])    . "',
          '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($ConexionBD, 
          $values["product_price"]) . "',
          '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($ConexionBD, 
          $values["product_quantity"]*$values["product_price"]) . "',
          NOW(),
          '$codigoVenta',
          '1'
           );
          ";
 } //end foreach

  if (mysqli_query($ConexionBD, $sql_cart) === true) {
      mysqli_query($ConexionBD, $sql_venta);
      mysqli_multi_query($ConexionBD, $order_details);
      unset($_SESSION["shopping_cartMT"]);
  } else {
     die('Error SQL: ' . mysqli_error($ConexionBD));
    } //fin de else, termina la insercion para el carrito on-line
} //end isset
?>
```

Las inserciones funcionan correctamente. Estoy atorado en esta parte de ¿cómo reducir stock y actualizar la tabla articulo?

Comment: YO te preguntaría y cuál es la llave primaria? Que sea única y auto incremental?

Comment: La tabla artículo no tiene clave primaria autoincrementable, tiene como campo varchar (20), esto se rellena con un algoritmo de números aleatorios.

Comment: OH genial duda aclarada

Comment: @ShadowPaz ¿puede orientarme en cómo aplicar un trigger para este caso?